# Azure Database Sync

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-sql-database

Not sure to understand the best way to do this. I have an application which runs with a ms sql db in a local server and I want to migrate this to Azure. I want to establish a sync between local and cloud db and be able to switch my connections string between local and cloud regularly to test if it's suitable to work with azure before switching completely to Azure.

I am have this issue with the MS SQL Data sync preview:
Unable to apply a row that exceeds the Maximum Application Transaction Size for table 'dbo.XXXXXX'.  Please increase the transaction size to be greater than the size of the largest row being synchronized

Shall I use the Microsoft.Synchronization framework to do my custom sync ? Is this a lot of work ? Or is there a way to allow the sync agent to synchronize heavy tables ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root cause of your sync failure is the row size of table dbo.XXX is 32278KB, which larger than the Data Sync support size of 24576KB. Here is a doc describing the limitations of Data Sync Service.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj590380.aspx.

Comment: thanks but this does not tell me how to achieve the synchronization

Answer (score 0):

I'm an engineer from SQL Data Sync team. The potential root cause of this issue is like Paul said. For confirmation, could you please provide the related Sync Group Id and Azure Subscription Id here (You can find the information in "PROPERTIES" tab of the specific Sync Group)? And then I'll do further check on our service backend.

Comment: This would be better suited as a comment to the question, rather than an "answer".

Comment: sync:19dc4e80-9006-4376-9a47-0e7f73e929aa_West Europe sub: d60b5064-4c86-49f1-adcf-face940731a5

Comment: @faisantp, the latest sync failed with error: Message: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Doc', table '\*DB.dbo.Al\*cs'. (I hide some characters in table name in case it's sensitive). You can check the full error message from Azure Portal. And for this error, could you please first check whether column 'Doc' of table 'dbo.Al\*cs' is set to "not allow NULL" in both your Azure and On-Premises databases? Also could you please let me know whether the value of Primary Key of table 'dbo.Al\*cs' will be updated in your scenario? As update PK value is currently not supported in SQL Data Sync.

Comment: Primary key is RelId, int, not allow null. Dbo.Al*cs Doc is set to not allow null in our local server. how do I managed that in Azure ?

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data

This is a known limitation of Azure Data Sync, try the Azure ADFv2 using the delta copy its simple and Effective for database sizes more then 20GB's